# In angular 2+ how to check url has proper image extension or not

Tags: javascript, angular

When angular receive the data from the API via HTTP call then how to check some property has an image or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to solve this real world example in a very easy way.
**organaization.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; 
export class OrganizationComponent implements OnInit {

 organizationObj:any = {
  logo: 'http://someurl.com/assets/images/'
  image: 'http://someurl.com/assets/images/someimg.jpg'
 };
 imgNoExt:boolean = false;

 // here is the simple image extension check function
 private urlImgHasExt(url){
    return(url.match(/\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$/) != null);
 }

 ngOnInit() {
    this.imgNoExt = this.urlImgHasExt(this.organizationObj.logo);
    console.log(this.imgNoExt) //this will return false value

    this.imgNoExt = this.urlImgHasExt(this.organizationObj.image);
    console.log(this.imgNoExt) //this will now return true value
 }
}
```